# VueJS Image Tag Source is not working, how can i fix it?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following `img` tag :

```
 <img class="logo" src="../../assets/logo/logo_blue.png">
```

project structure

[image: project structure]

I don't know why but I only get the following error message:

> GET http://localhost:8080/assets/logo/logo_blue.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: did you try `<img class="logo" src="../../../assets/logo/logo_blue.png">`?

Comment: What sort of project is this? Vue CLI (v3), vue-cli (v2), Nuxt, something else?

Comment: Vue CLI v3 with framework7 - still not working

Answer (score 3):

try `<img class="logo" src="@/assets/logo/logo_blue.png">`
here '@' refers to root directory

Comment: This entirely depends on the answer to [my question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729793/vuejs-image-tag-source-is-not-working-how-can-i-fix-it#comment92385441_52729793) but you're probably right

Comment: If it's a Nuxt project though, it should be `src="~assets/logo/logo_blue.png"`. See https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/

Comment: yes that's true, either works fine. The has tag is for vuejs

Comment: Nuxt is a project architecture for Vue projects. I think OP _is_ using Nuxt due to the `pages` directory in their screenshot.

Comment: @F0rce did you try `~assets/logo/logo_blue.png`?

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

`<img class="logo" src="./assets/logo/logo_blue.png">`

I believe the path to that image entirely depends on the relative path between the page and image at *deployment time*. If you're not using HTML5 history mode, this `./assets/` prefix should always work.